# SQL Alchemy Query with Eagerly Loaded Relationships?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm having trouble using SA's eager relationship loading within a query.

I have two tables declared like so:

```
class Score(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Score'

    school = relationship("School", backref='score')
    SchoolKey = Column('SchoolKey', Integer, primary_key=True)


class School(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'School'

    SchoolKey = deferred(Column('SchoolKey', Integer, primary_key=True))
    SchoolName = Column('SchoolName', String)
    SchoolDistrict = deferred(Column('SchoolDistrict', String), group = 'district')
    SchoolDistrictID = deferred(Column('SchoolDistrictID', integer), group = 'district')
```

I want to query my Score table with a filter condition coming from the School table as concisely as possible. So I have the relationship eagerly loaded.

Right now when I query I cannot get it to work:

```
session.query(Score).filter(School.SchoolName == 'RandomName')
```

(this actually just crashes my computer)  **Anyone have an idea how to get this to work?**

Context: I know this sounds trivial for my example, but Score is a fact table at the heart of >10 tables.  I really want to avoid writing 10 .join parts to any query to filter.  So I want to avoid something like this:

```
session.query(Score).join(School).filter(School.SchoolName == 'RandomName')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary solution: Just accepting that I need to write a join for all the dimension tables:

```
session.query(Score).join(School).filter(School.SchoolName == 'RandomName')
```